# Do I need to run NoSQL databases on some cloud environments before I benchmark them?

Tags: cassandra, cloud, benchmarking, riak, nosql

I have installed Cassandra (from DataStax) and Riak in my computer. I want to benchmark them with varieties workload and record size. I am using YCSB tool.

Do I need to use any public datacentre/cloud environment before I benchmark, or the Databases are already running in some cloud environments?

Comment: "cloud" is such an utterly useless/moronic buzzword. **EVERYTHING** is in the cloud, because it still just boils down to client/server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, I believe if I follow your question, is no.

It is quite possible to benchmark the database on your local computer without having to set up environments in the "cloud". If you have the databases correctly setup on your local machine and point YCSB to them properly your should be able to run the tests.

There are of course some additional considerations in benchmarking like:

- Why are you benchmarking Cassandra and Riak? What is the use case? The two databases are similar but have different ideal use cases and different performance profiles. Just benchmarking them head to head via YCSB will only tell you a small part of the story.
- Testing a single node of either database is also not going to give you a realistic picture of their performance as they are designed to be used as clusters of nodes.
- If you have a specific use case you want to test you might consider writing your own benchmarking test vs using YCSB.